# Lotus Notes - Saving Corrupt Attachment Programmatically - NotesEmbeddedObject

Tags: c#, .net, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

I have an `NSF` that contains an email message with two attachments. One of the attachments is corrupt, and if I attempt to save it, Notes displays this message `The attachment may be corrupted. Would you like to continue with the available data?`

If I click Yes, Notes saves the corrupt attachment to the directory I specify. This is good.

I would like to do the same thing using the object model in C#. If I run `NotesEmbeddedObject.ExtractFile()`, I receive this exception message: `Notes error: Encoded Data Checksum Mismatch - Attachment may be corrupted`. No version of the file is written to the directory I specify.

I would like for the code to write the corrupted version to a directory. How can I do this?

Existing Code:

```
//BEGIN Extract Attachment
//nItem is a NotesItem
if (nItem.type == IT_TYPE.ATTACHMENT)
{
    try
    {
        string pAttachment = ((object[])nItem.Values)[0].ToString();
        NotesDocument NDoc =  NotesConnectionDatabase.AllDocuments.GetNthDocument(i);
        NotesEmbeddedObject Neo = NDoc.GetAttachment(pAttachment);
        NDoc.GetAttachment(pAttachment).ExtractFile(@"D:\projects\xxx\Attach\" + pAttachment);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string eMessage = e.Message;
        Console.WriteLine(eMessage);
    }
}
//END Extract Attachment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid not.

The `NotesEmbeddedObject.ExtractFile` method attempts to extract the attachment, but there's a checksum mismatch, and as soon as it gets that error, it throws an exception.

I don't know of any other Notes back-end classes that deal with attachments (maybe someone else does...)